# Write to MySQL on mouseover

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mouseover

After months of testing, I'm not succeeding to create a script that writes a logtext to the MySQL when a div gets a mouseover.

I think I have to use $.ajax, the only problem is, is that ajax (still) is the language which I'm not very good at.

One of the 100 things i've tried:

```
<?
echo "<div id='div0' rel=".$someid.">Some dynamic text</div>";
?>

<script>
           $('.div0').mouseover(function() {
           $('#result').load('../../../system/molog.php?cid='+$(this).attr('rel');
           });
</script>
```

Who can help?

Comment: You're using a class selector instead of an id selector to select the div, the div seems to be missing a closing tag.

Comment: Yes, you would indeed have to use AJAX to post from JavaScript to MySQL, as you'd need to use a PHP page as an intermediary. Simply set up a JavaScript conditional that POSTs the data (which I assume would be a timestamp or something), and set up a PHP page that checks whether the `$_POST` is set. If it is, insert it into the database. And you've also got the wrong selector.

Comment: <div id='div0' is $('#div0') not $('.div0')

Comment: Thanks Musa, it has to be a #, the shown script is jus a small part of the script, I forgot to add the </div>.. it is in the original scripts though.

Comment: @ObsidianAge, do you know a tutorial so I can read how I can accomplish this?

Comment: well, absolutely you'll need to use ajax.  Which means you need to dive in and learn javascript.  Jquery makes ajax fairly easy, so go brush up on the jquery docs.

Comment: Obsidian answered the question basically. Here's what OP needs to Google: 1) JS on mouse over function(event){}  2) $.post, $.get, just AJAX in general   3) SQL INSERT query (https://wbr.bz/QueryPro to learn prepared statements) on the PHP file called by AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there's a much better way to do this, but since I'm on a phone that's dying and you have been waiting a year...

```
var info = $("#div0").html();
// if Js in a php file you can do var info = <?php echo $logtext ?>; To bring it to JS 
$.get("phpfilehere.php", {info:info}, function(data){
alert(data);
});
```

The mouseover function...

```
$("#div0").on("mouseover", function(){ 
// my JS code above goes here
 });
```

PHP file:

```
if(isset($_GET['info'])){
$log = $_GET['info']; 
// Put ur stuff here, make sure u only echo when u want ur php script to stop and be sent back to Ajax function as data var.
// insert $log  
echo "test";
} else {
echo "no get info supplied": 
}
```

And here is a tool I made to teach people how to write prepared statements for SQL queries :) if you need it...

http://wbr.bz/QueryPro/index.php?query_type=prepared_insert

Comment: For the script I have to create the logging to, I use a similar version of:
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-ajax-live-search.php

The problem is, when I use the jQueryversion which is in this tutorial, the script works flawless but the logging doesn't work.
If I'm using the latest jQuery, the logging works fine, but the real time search script becomes extremely slow. And stalls / stops the browser.
It looks like something goes in an infinite loop and uses all the available memory.